# Filling a <div> container with bulk text from another file using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to have a `<div>` container on an html page load up text from a different file. (I am currently testing this just locally on my machine.) The most simple example of what I'm doing is below.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#Target').load('x.html');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Homepage</h1>
    <div id="Target">
    </div>
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

**x.html**

```
Hello, World!
```

I have checked and it seems that JQuery is being loaded ok, but the "Hello World" text doesn't load into the `<div>` container.

I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm not seeing.

The full goal of this is to have a set of collapsible buttons that loads up different text depending on which button you click into a container.

Comment: No console messages / errors?

Comment: Probably CORS blocking. But as Graham asked, any error logs?

Comment: Try that in Firefox. If you are using Chrome or other CORS blocking browser, it won't work. Or you could try it on a server.

Comment: This won't work on chrome because of security flag regarding access to local file

Comment: Yes there's a console error:

'XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///...x.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.'

Comment: @Christina So run a local server or check it http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

Comment: Yes you're right, it was a chrome problem it seems to work in safari. What a pain! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments, the problem was that chrome wouldn't allow me to use the second file because of the security protocols. Answer is either:

- Use a different browser (Safari or Firefox worked for me)
- Put it on a local server